# Styles broken when using Release to deploy a website

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-4, deployment, release, microsoft-web-deploy

I Developed a website using MVC4 and deployed my site using **Web Deploy** and the **Release** option.
If i use the Debug option, everything is fine. Here are the published URL's:

- Broken Styles (published with Release option): http://bitmake.azurewebsites.net/
- Correct Styles (published with Debug option): http://www.bitmake.com.br/

Can someone point me whats wrong?

Comment: Is the css file properly loaded ? Any 404 errors ?

Comment: No 404, everything loaded right

Comment: Can't access the website. Is their any console errors ?

Answer (score 0):

When I used chrome's developer console to look into the source, correct one shows a Content folder with css and fontawesome folder, while the other site shows bundles and js folder. The CSS file in the bundles folder is also showing some error regarding minification failure. Hope this helps.
Amazing UI btw.
[image]